# Trying to avoid excessive iteration when creating a custom-sized array

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, list

When writing a program to process a file, I often find myself doing something like this:

```
string[] allLinesFromFile = null;
int arraySize = File.ReadAllLines(_path).Length;
allLinesFromFile = new string[arraySize];
allLinesFromFile = File.ReadAllLines(_path);
progressBar1.Maximum = arraySize;
progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
```

It strikes me that in doing so I may be iterating through the file more times than necessary (there are usually thousands of lines in the file). Is there a way to create a custom-sized array without the excess iteration?

Comment: `var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(_path);`   The ReadAllLines method creates an array for you, you just need to assign it to a local variable.

Comment: @Plutonix I should have realized that `File.ReadAllLines` creates the custom-sized array internally. If you put this in the form of an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the size of the returned array:

```
string[] allLinesFromFile = null;    
allLinesFromFile = File.ReadAllLines(_path);
progressBar1.Maximum = allLinesFromFile.Length;
progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
```